# Compute $\int_{0}^{\infty} \left( \cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-2 \right)dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I don't remember how to solve this integral ;_;

I tried $u=\frac{1}{x}$ to format it into a frullani integral, but I ended up having this:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{u^2}\left ( \cos(u)+\frac{\sin(u)}{u}-2 \right )du$$

Is there a trig-identity I'm not aware of or is there a better way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rewrite the original integrand as

$$I = \int_0^\infty\frac{1}{2}\left(2x\sin\frac{1}{x}-\cos\frac{1}{x}-1\right)+\frac{3}{2}\left(\cos\frac{1}{x}-1\right)\:dx \equiv I_1 + I_2$$

The first one has a direct antiderivative

$$I_1 = \frac{1}{2}\left[x^2\sin\frac{1}{x}-x\right]_0^\infty = 0$$

and the second one can be done with your substitution and the half angle identity

$$I_2 = \frac{3}{2}\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos u - 1}{u^2}du = -\frac{3}{2}\int_0^\infty \frac{2\sin^2 \frac{u}{2}}{u^2}du = \boxed{-\frac{3\pi}{4}}$$

which happens to be the final answer.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!! Now I remember!!!! I made this integral because of the (cos(x)-1)/x^2 trick!!

Answer (score 2):

*Since @Ninad Munshi provided an elegant solution for the definite integral, I write this answer for your curiosity.*

What you could do (if you want more than the limit itself) is to focus on the antiderivative. All of them are simple if you know the sine integral function.

This would give for

$$I=\int\frac{1}{u^2}\left ( \cos(u)+\frac{\sin(u)}{u}-2 \right )\,du$$
the result
$$I=-\frac{3 }{2}\text{Si}(u)-\frac{\sin (u)}{2
   u^2}+\frac{2}{u}-\frac{3 \cos (u)}{2 u}+C$$

No problem around $u=0$ since, by Taylor,
$$-\frac{3 }{2}\text{Si}(u)-\frac{\sin (u)}{2
   u^2}+\frac{2}{u}-\frac{3 \cos (u)}{2 u}=-\frac{2 u}{3}+\frac{u^3}{60}+O\left(u^5\right)$$ So, a value of $0$ at the lower bound.

Now, when $u$ is large
$$\text{Si}(u)=\frac{\pi }{2}-\frac{\cos (u)}{u}-\frac{\sin (u)}{u^2}+\cdots$$

So, as a total
$$\int_{0}^{p} \left( \cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-2 \right)\,dx=-\frac{3 \pi }{4}+\frac{2}{3 p}-\frac{1}{60
   p^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^5}\right)$$ which is extremely accurate even for small values of $p$.

Using for example $p=10$, the exact result is
$-2.289544487$ while the approximation gives $-2.289544490$.

Answer (score 2):

$$ \begin{align} I &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \left(\cos \left(\frac{1}{x} \right)  + x \sin \left(\frac{1}{x} \right) -2 \right) \, \mathrm dx \\ &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{u^{2}} \left(\cos(u)+ \frac{\sin (u)}{u} -2 \right) \, \mathrm du \\ &= \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{u^{2}} \left(\cos(u)+ \frac{\sin (u)}{u} -2 \right) \, \mathrm du  \\ &= \frac{1}{2} \,  \Re \, \operatorname{PV} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{u^{2}} \left(e^{iu} -\frac{ie^{iu}}{u} -2 + \frac{i}{u} \right) \, \mathrm du \\   &\overset{(1)}{=}\frac{1}{2} \, \Re \left(  \pi i\operatorname{Res} \left[\frac{1}{z^{2}} \left(e^{iz}- \frac{ie^{iz}}{z} -2 + \frac{i}{z}\right), \, 0 \right] \right)  \\&= \frac{1}{2} \, \Re\left(\pi i \left( \frac{3i}{2} \right)  \right) \\ &= - \frac{3 \pi}{4}.\end{align}$$

$(1)$
Integrate around a closed semicircular contour in the upper half-plane that is indented at the origin.

At $z=0$, $$ \begin{align} \frac{1}{z^{2}} \left(e^{iz}- \frac{ie^{iz}}{z} -2 + \frac{i}{z} \right) &= \frac{1}{z^{2}} \left(\left(1
+iz+\frac{(iz)^{2}}{2!}  + O(z^{3}) \right) \left(-\frac{i}{z}+1 \right)-2 + \frac{i}{z} \right) \\ &= \frac{1}{z^{2}} \left(\left(-\frac{i}{z}+ 1+ 1 + iz+ \frac{iz}{2} + O(z^{2}) \right) -2+\frac{i}{z} \right) \\ &=\frac{3i}{2z}  + O(1). \end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

Integrate by parts twice
\begin{align} & \int_{0}^{\infty}\left( \cos \frac{1}{x} + x \sin \frac{1}{x}  -2 \right) dx \\
= &\int_{0}^{\infty}
\left( \frac1{2x}\cos \frac{1}{x} +\frac12 \sin \frac{1}{x}  -\frac1x \right)\overset{ibp} {d(x^2)}\\
=& \int_{0}^{\infty}
\left( \cos \frac{1}{x}-1\right)\overset{ibp}{dx}-\int_0^\infty \frac1{2x}\sin \frac{1}{x} {dx}\\
=& -\frac32 \int_0^\infty \frac1{x}\sin \frac{1}{x} {dx}\overset{x\to\frac1x}=-\frac32\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x}{dx}=-\frac{3\pi}4
\end{align}